# Can you specify column descriptions for a view in a DDL statement in BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I know this is possible with a `CREATE TABLE` statement but I don't see a way to do it with views. I know views support descriptions on columns since I can edit them in the web GUI. I'd like to avoid deploying views with a separate "annotation" file if possible.

I'd like to do something like the following

```
CREATE VIEW Sandbox.vtest
as
SELECT 1 AS TestField [WITH] OPTIONS(description="An INTEGER field")
```

This would also work especially now that scripting is possible

```
ALTER VIEW Sandbox.vtest 
ALTER COLUMN TestField 
SET OPTIONS(description="An INTEGER field")
```

If it's not possible I'm hoping someone from Google could comment on any future plan to add this functionality. That could at least guide my CI/CD development.

Comment: This is not currently possible, but you could consider submitting a feature request. See https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

Comment: From GCP Docs...

Note: When you create a view using the UI, you cannot add a label, description, or expiration time. You can add these optional properties when you create a view using the CLI or API. After you create a view using the BigQuery web UI, you can add an expiration, description, and labels. For more information, see Updating views. 

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views

Comment: @ElliottBrossard can you please promote your comment to an answer? :)

Comment: Agreed, @ElliottBrossard, I'll mark it as the answer if you move it.

Comment: Sure, added a simple answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not currently possible, but you could consider submitting a feature request. Use this link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0

After you create a logical view, you can navigate to it in the BigQuery UI and then set the description or other attributes.